# Recursive view causes loop

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a recursive treeview in Angular2 with Firebase. The "root" loads just fine, but getting deeper into the tree doesn't work. I believe it is because I call a function getting another observable in my view:

```
<ul>
    <div class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
        <li *ngFor="let parent of parents | async" (mouseover)="onMouseOver(parent)">
            <div *ngIf="parent.children">
                <div [class.over] = "parent.position == hoveredParent" [class.selected] = "parent.position == selectedParent"  tabindex="0"> 
                    <span>{{ parent.name }} </span>
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="parent.expanded">
                    <tree-view [parents]="getChilden(parent.$key)" [hoveredParent]="hoveredParent" [selectedParent]="selectedParent" (selectedParentChange)="selectParentChange($event);"></tree-view>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {Parent} from '../parent';
import {TreeService} from '../tree.service'
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'tree-view',
  templateUrl: './tree-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree-view.component.css']
})
export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit {
  treeService: any;
  children: any[] = [];
  constructor(af: AngularFire) { 
    this.treeService = new TreeService(af);
  }

  @Input() parents: any;
  @Input() hoveredParent: number;
  @Input() selectedParent: number;
  @Output() selectedParentChange = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onMouseOver(parent: Parent) {
    this.hoveredParent = parent.position;
    console.log(parent);
  }

  onSelect(parent: Parent) {
    this.selectedParent = parent.position;
    this.selectedParentChange.emit({
        value: this.selectedParent
    })
  }

  selectParentChange(event: any) {
    this.selectedParent = event.value;
  }

  getChildren(key: any) {
    return this.treeService.getChildren(key);
  }
}
```

The getChildren function in the service

```
  getChildren(keyParent: any) {
    return ( this.af.database.list('parents/' + keyParent + '/children'));
  }
```

If the parent is supposed to be expanded I try to get the underlying parents with a query to firebase in which I look up the corresponding children. However if I do so (when logging instead of trying to return something) it keeps logging the observable. 
Another way I thought could work was trying to get the objects itself, however this doesn't work either because of the async pipe in the for loop.

I have been trying to get this to work for a couple of weeks but I can't figure out how to solve this.
Has anyone an idea on how to tackle this?

Thanks in advance,
Dominik

Comment: Hard to tell. You didn't even include the code for the component. Can you provide a Plunker? Plunker provides a ready to use Angular2 TS template.

Comment: I look into Plunker and put it in here

Comment: Furthermore I will try to find a way to putit in a plunker without revealing my credentials ;)

Comment: Just create a dummy service that returns test data instead of calling out to the Firebase server.